# Is it possible to grant role privileges to a user by document (not collection) in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, role, access-control

I am working on a database for investigation purposes. I want to make some of that information public but other pieces of information are highly confidential.

I want to create a user and grant access only to the public information inside a document of a collection. For example in my collection "people", i want to show the name but not the phone number:

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5910e7abce41fe759ebb1720"),
   "name" : "name",
   "phone" : "999999999"
}
```

How can i achieve this? I only found how to grant User-Defined Roles by collection.

```
db.createRole(
{
 role: "myClusterwideAdmin",
 privileges: [
   { resource: { cluster: true }, actions: [ "addShard" ] },
   { resource: { db: "config", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find", "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
   { resource: { db: "users", collection: "usersCollection" }, actions: [ "update", "insert", "remove" ] },
   { resource: { db: "", collection: "" }, actions: [ "find" ] }
 ],
 roles: [
   { role: "read", db: "admin" }
 ]
},
{ w: "majority" , wtimeout: 5000 }
)
```

Should i create a "public information" collection or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot grant rights for document... But you can do [views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) what shows only that public information.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not yet on (and cannot upgrade to) MongoDB 3.4 then views won't be an option. In that case you will need to resort to providing the public information in a different collection.  You can always reference the _id belonging to the documents in the sensitive collection to keep your data model intact.